# MKMapView responds to touches even though it is behind an annotation

Tags: ios, mapkit

I have a custom annotation view that takes up a large portion of the screen.  Inside it I have a UITableView and some labels.

The UITableView handles cell selection correctly.  However, if I double tap on the UITableView  or anywhere on the custom annotation view, the map will zoom.

First off I'd love to understand how that is happening.   And secondly how to stop it from happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have figured this out.  What is happening is that the MKMapView has gesture recognizers attached to it.

I fixed part of the issue here by subclassing the MKMapView and implementing  shouldReceiveTouch.   Double taps are still getting through the annotation view, but that is less of an issue.  It was the single tap that was the real usability problem.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    UIView * v = touch.view;
    while( v ){
    if( [v isKindOfClass:[SPAnnotationView class]] ){
        SPAnnotationView * aV = (SPAnnotationView *)v;
        if( [aV isExtendedAnnotation]){
            return NO;
        }
    }
        v = v.superview;
    }

    return [super gestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:touch];

   }
```